# Galaxy S7 stopped working - Want to retrieve files

Tags: data-recovery

I have a Galaxy S7 whose screen died. I can connect the phone to a PC using a USB cable, and the PC recognizes the device. However, since the device is in "USB Charge" mode, I cannot access the directory structure on the phone to access files.

Is there a way to send a command to the phone via USB cable to change the settings?

If I can change the USB settings, I will be able to see the phone's file structure, and I will be able to retrieve pictures on the phone. (I do not have any extra storage card on the phone.)

Thanks!
Jon

Comment: "The screen died" means that you cannot see anything on it at all, or simply you can see the screen but the touch doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The screen is black. Nothing on the screen. There is no sign of life whatsoever, other than when I plug a USB cable in and connect it to a computer, the computer does recognize that there is a device connected and installs the drivers. Thanks for your inquiry and interest in helping out!

Jon